# How do I get a constant column in a Django ORM?

Tags: python, django

I am studying ORM.
However, there are some things I don't understand even after reading the documentation.

How do I get a constant column in a Django ORM?

SQL is here.

```sql
select *, 'a' as a from book;
```

This is the query set I tried

```py
Book.objects.annotate(a=Value('a'))
```

The error is here.

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executing your code, I get the following error:

```
FieldError('Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field')
```

Which means django doesn't know the type that your annotated field should result in.

To fix this, you need to wrap your annotation in an **[`ExpressionWrapper`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions)**:

```
from django.db.models import Value, ExpressionWrapper

Book.objects.annotate(a=ExpressionWrapper(
    Value('a'), 
    output_field=models.CharField(max_length=45),
))
```

Comment: Succeeded. Thank you very much.